# Modifying date to enable search in mysql DateTime format

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, time

I have an UI, in which we which we select a date range, and then perform a query to check orders within that range.

So the valid formats accepted are

a) 2013-04-01 17:00:00 - 2013-04-16 18:00:00

b) 2013-04-01 17:00:00 - 2013-04-16

c) 2013-04-01 - 2013-04-16

I split it in ruby to give me start_date and end_date. I don't have to touch the start time, as it ready for the sql query.

But the end_date has to be modified because to perform a ranged query `created_at BETWEEN '2013-04-01 17:00:00' AND '2013-04-16'` does not give me the results of 16th which should be included in the result set. (As it compares to 2013-04-16 00:00:00)

So this is the working solution, I came up with

```
end_date = Time.parse(end_date).strftime("%T")=="00:00:00" ? (end_date.to_s) + " 23:59:59" : end_date.to_s
```

Is there a better way to do this as the above looks quite confusing? (Looking or 1-2 line answers, not more)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `DateTime.parse(str)` method:

```
date_str = "2013-04-16"
date = DateTime.parse(date_str)
#=> Tue, 16 Apr 2013 00:00:00 +0000

date_time_str = "2013-04-16 18:00:00"
date = DateTime.parse(date_time_str)
#=> Tue, 16 Apr 2013 18:00:00 +0000
```

And then you could test the  `.hour` (or `.minute`) and set the `end_date` to `end_of_day` if no time was selected:

```
end_date = (date.hour == 0 && date.minute == 0) ? date.end_of_day : date
```

---

**Little improvement:** You could test if the parsed date is equal to the beginning of this date (no hours/minutes/seconds):

```
date = DateTime.parse("2013-12-12")
#=> Thu, 12 Dec 2013 00:00:00 +0000
date.beginning_of_day
#=> Thu, 12 Dec 2013 00:00:00 +0000
end_date = (date.beginning_of_day == date) ? date.end_of_day : date
#=> Thu, 12 Dec 2013 23:59:59 +0000
```

---

**To solve the problem** when user enters a DateTime like `2013-04-16 00:00:00`, you can use `.include?` to check if the string contains the '`00:00:00`' part:

```
date_str = "2013-04-16 00:00:00"
date = DateTime.parse(date_str)

end_date = date if date_str.include?('00:00:00') # means the user explicitly wants the time at 00:00 and 00 second
end_date ||= (date.beginning_of_day == date) ? date.end_of_day : date # set end_date if end_date.nil?
```

Comment: Looks so much better, and easy to read. Giving it a try in irb now.

Comment: Works on irb..See no reason why it shouldn't work in the rails application.

Comment: MrYoshji, so much of a hurry? :-)

Comment: Ahah yeah sorry I wanted to pass the 5 400 rep... x)

Comment: What if the guy enters, date_time_str = "2013-04-16 00:00:00" , then even that will be converted to 2013-04-16 23:59:59?

Comment: Updated, there is actually tons of ways to check this, I am not sure mine is the most explicit/readable/short!

Comment: MrYoshji - It's ok, Let's see what I come up with. Thanks anyways.